# Creating graph in loop from Boost library c++

Tags: c++, loops, boost, graph

I am trying to convert myself from R to C++ and am struggling with a particular graph problem. I have a String Matrix called "Gra" as below.

```
      int main(){
      string Gra[4][5] =   {{"V0", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"}, 
                            {"V5", "V6", "NA", "NA", "V7"},
                            {"V8", "V9", "NA", "NA", "V10"},
                            {"V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15"}};
```

Where "V0" represents a node and "NA" is not. This matrix came from the matrix called "base"

```
   int base[4][5] = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
                    {1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};


typedef float Weight;
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, Weight> WeightProperty;
typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string> NameProperty;

typedef boost::adjacency_list < boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
NameProperty, WeightProperty > Graph;

typedef boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor Vertex;

typedef boost::property_map < Graph, boost::vertex_index_t >::type IndexMap;
typedef boost::property_map < Graph, boost::vertex_name_t >::type NameMap;

typedef boost::iterator_property_map < Vertex*, IndexMap, Vertex, Vertex& > PredecessorMap;
typedef boost::iterator_property_map < Weight*, IndexMap, Weight, Weight& > DistanceMap;

 Graph g;
```

Where the problem is, trying to describe the graph in a loop. I would like to declare the nodes as

```
    Vertex V0 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V0"), g);            // Struggling to implement this in a loop
    Vertex V1 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V1"), g);
    Vertex V2 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V2"), g);
    Vertex V3 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V3"), g); 
    Vertex V4 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V4"), g);
    Vertex V5 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V5"), g);
    Vertex V6 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V6"), g);
    Vertex V7 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V7"), g); 
    Vertex V8 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V8"), g);
    Vertex V9 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V9"), g);
    Vertex V10 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V10"), g);
    Vertex V11 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V11"), g); 
    Vertex V12 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V12"), g);
    Vertex V13 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V13"), g);
    Vertex V14 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V14"), g);
    Vertex V15 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V15"), g);
```

How I have tried to replicate this is through a loop like this.

```
for ( int i=0; i < 4; i++)  // So this will run along all elements of our base vector
{       
  for ( int j=0; j < 5; j++)    // Length is the number of elements in our array
  {
  if( !(Gra[i][j] == "NA")) // Whilst going along each element inspecting whether it is a true node
  {
      Vertex Gra[i][j] = boost::add_vertex(std::Gra[i][j], g);  // This is where the problem is
  }
  }
```

}

So the problem comes from using a string to define this object of class Vertex. Could any body help me? I'm pretty sure this is a naming convention issue that I'm struggling with. If this is solved then I can solve the rest of my problems in terms of creating the edges which I also have the same problem of trying to call an object of class "vertex" using a string.

Thanks in advance Cyrill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `!Gra[i][j] == "NA"` will not do what you expect it to. It will *first* check that `Gra[i][j]` is not "false" and then compare the boolean result with the string `"NA"`.

Instead either use parentheses around the equality check, or do a not-equal check. So either

```
!(Gra[i][j] == "NA")
```

or

```
Gra[i][j] != "NA"
```

---

There's also the problem that you declare a local array-of-arrays variable `Gra` inside the inner loop, which will cause clashes with your outer `Gra` variable. I guess that's why you use `std::Gra` there, but `Gra` is not declared in the standard namespace. Neither can you use `::Gra` because `Gra` is not declared in the global namespace either.

Instead of declaring a new variable inside the inner loop, declare an array `Vertexes` outside the loop:

```
Vertex Vertexes[4][5];
```

Then use that variable to store the result of `boost::add_vertex`.

Comment: Awesome these are the things I miss. I could change that to !base[I][j] = 0

Comment: The problem that I need help with is that boost wants to see - Vertex V15 = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V15"),g);      But I can only give it  Vertex "V15" = boost::add_vertex(std::string("V15"), g);

Comment: @Cyrillm_44 How about a [hash table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) of `Vertex` objects, with a string (e.g. `"V15"`) as the key? Instead of the `Vertexes` array in my answer I mean.